# Good Method for Processing some Similar Images

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I need to process some images in a real-time situation. I am receiving the images from a camera using OpenCV. The language I use is C++. An example of the images is attached. After applying some threshold filters I have an image like this, Of course there may be some pixel noises here and there, but not that much.

[image]

I need to detect the center and the rotation of the squares, and the center of the white circles. I'm totally clueless about how to do it, as it needs to be really fast. The number of the squares can be predefined. Any help would be great, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the following straight forward approch too slow?

- Binarize the image, so that the originally green background is black and the rest (black squares are white dots) are white.
- Use cv::findContours.
- Get the centers.
- Binarize the image, so that the everything except the white dots is black.
- Use cv::findContours.
- Get the centers.
- Assign every dot contours to the squate contour, for that is an inlier.
- Calculate the squares rotations by the angle of the line between their centers and the centers of their dots.

Comment: I need to do this about 20 times per second. I will just try this method and update this post about it. Thanks.

Comment: OK, 50ms is not much, but depending on your hardware it could perhaps be possible. If not you could try if a reduces resolution will still be precise enough for what you are doing.

Comment: OK! I did this, and also found out that OpenCV has a function to approximate the polygon (cvApproxPoly). And I guess the problem is solved. Thanks again!

Comment: Just some notes. I binarized the image once, so that the green background becomes white, the black squares remain black, and the white dots become white. In this manner, not only I get the contours, but I can also use the Tree output mode for contours, and will automatically know which square each white dot belongs to.